# php onclick on iframe and load the source in another iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I am trying to make something where you can click in the scroll navigation, On the video you want to see. This video then opens in the black box next to it.
Right now the video's are still shown in the div where they stand. 
What would be the best steps I have to take to realize this?

I have tried something with an onclick function on the iframes but I think that isn't what  I should do. You can see the code also beneath the picture
You can see the picture beneath:

[image]

```html
echo '<div class="overzicht">';


while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $link = $row['link'];
    $newLink = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $link);
    echo
        '<div class="scrollbar">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
                  <iframe onclick="showVideo('.$newLink.')" src="'.$newLink.'" ></iframe>
              </div>
          </div>';
echo '</div>';

function showVideo($link){
    $idLink = $link;
    echo '<iframe src="'.$idLink.'" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: where is this method `showVideo()` and where are you calling the `showFunction()` method?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to name the function showVideo instead of showFunction

Comment: well, if you're trying to use a JS call to a PHP method, you can't. You need to use Ajax.

Comment: And what if I made javascript of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!-- html + javascript, copy src from iframe1 to iframe2 -->
    <iframe onclick="myFunc(this);" src="...link"> ... </iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe2"></iframe >
    <script>
        function myFunc(el1) // el1 (this) = tag, where you use onclick
            {
            var el2 = document.getElementById('iframe2');
            el2.src = el1.src;
            }
    </script>
```

or can change

```
        <iframe onclick="myFunc2(this.src);" src="...link"> ... </iframe>
    <script>
        function myFunc2(link)
            {
            document.getElementById('iframe2').src = link;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: I am sorry that is not it

Comment: Then, i not understand, what you need. Php code -> php server -> generate html / js code -> send to user. Javascript on user have only html code. If you can change src, you must use javascript.
May be, you can change source iframe from image? 
<img src=image1 onclick="myFunc2('link1');">
<img src=image2 onclick="myFunc2('link2');">

Comment: yeah I think I need javascript. 
But can you click on an iframe without starting it?

Comment: ??? Iframe starting with add src. Onclick, you can use on img, div, other element. In javascript, object tag, you can get by 
<anything id='tagid'></anything>
<anything id='tagid' tag src="a" title="b" href="c" value="f"> text </anything>
tag=document.getElementById('tagid')
alert(tag.id); alert(tag.src); alert(tag.title); alert(tag.href); alert(tag.href); alert(tag.value); alert(tag.innerHTML);